# Are there distinct phases of amorphous ice?

Tags: phase, glass

Amorphous ice is a solid phase of water that lacks crystal structure. It is stable below about 150K, above which it converts to crystalline ice.

There are four phases of amorphous ice: low medium, high, and very high density. Medium density is a very recent discovery and can be created by grinding ice at 77K.

Do these phases exist on a spectrum? There is no "in between" for different *crystalline* phases. But amorphous states do not have a precisely defined structure. If so there would be an amorphous ice with any density between 0.95 and 1.25 g/cm^3.

Comment: Given the different ice phases, it is conceivable that there could be amorphous ices with different radial distribution functions and a first order transition to a different radial distribution function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**According to Wikipedia, yes**

[Polyamorphism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyamorphism) occurs when there is a *first order* phase transition between two glass phases. Water ice is one of the examples.

Glass phases are never thermodynamicly stable, the substance at the given T and P would rather be in a crystalline (or in very rare cases quaiscrystalline) phase.

A glass-glass phase transition only occurs when the molecules are kinetically free enough rearrange a bit but *not* free enough to find the crystal phase. In ice, which *really wants to crystalize* it's a minor miracle that such a transition can be observed.